# Access the field class from within FieldItemList (D8)

Tags: forms, 8

When I would like to get the values inserted in a form, I use:

```
$form_state->getValue('myfield');
```

If I would like to have some information on the field definition, I use:

```
$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->myfield->getfieldDefinition();
```

Every time I check the class resulting from the following statement:

```
$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->myfield
```

It is of the type `Drupal\\Core\\Field\\FieldItemList` which is fine for getting/setting the values

Suppose that "myfield" is of the type "language_field" defined in `\Drupal\languagefield\Plugin\Field\FieldType\LanguageItem`.

This class have a public function

```
public function getNativeName()
```

To get the full name of the language.

But My question is: how to access this function fromwithin the FieldItemList object? (Same problem arise with many other field type)

Added info:

With the help of @Eyal, I could access my object method:

```
$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->myfield->get($delta)->getNativeName()‌​;
```

But this is valid only if the entity is already saved.

In the case of a new (or edited) item, the entity doesn't store the new value. Here is the code for what I am trying to explain:

The 2 variables will have the same value if I open and save the form without change, but this will not be the case if I update the item at delta=1.

```
function my_validate($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $val_by_entity=$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->myfield->get(1)->value;
  $val_by_form_state_value=$form_state->getValue(['myfield', 1, 'value']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to understand that the entity object in question does not have a property called myfield.

Drupal uses something called magic properties to mask the get method required for retrieving the field item list. See [FieldableEntityInterface::get()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21FieldableEntityInterface.php/function/FieldableEntityInterface%3A%3Aget/8.2.x) for more information.

The second thing you should know, is that drupal treats all fields as multi value. That means that a field that is defined to have a single value would still be represented a list with a single item.

Finally, to answer your question, you can either use the [FieldItemListInterface::get()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21ListInterface.php/function/ListInterface%3A%3Aget/8.2.x) method to get the field item object, it you can access it as though it was an array.

`$entity->get('myfield')->get(0);`

*OR*

`$entity->myfield[0];`

Comment: This is a really nice answer: I could access my LanguageItem object by using `$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->myfield>get($delta)->getNativeName();`

Comment: Thanks :) , I try to avoid magic properties because I enjoy the type hinting provided by the IDE. When I write `$entity->myfield` the IDE doesn't know what is the type returned by the magic property.

Comment: Unfortunately, one issue is remaining: if $delta is a newly added item (or changed item), its value can be obtained with `$form_state->getValue('myfield')[$delta]['value']`; but the FormObject doesn't contains yet this new value. Thus I can't use `getNativeName()` for this new item

Comment: It all depends on the context. After the buildEntity method runs, the updated values are set on the entity. FYI the getValue method of form_state can accept arrays `$form_state->getValue(['myfield', $delta, 'value']);` the advantage is that if it is not found no exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! The context is form_validate and/or form_submit.

Comment: It should be available in both of these methods.

Comment: I am not sure... see my updated question with a test to show that it is not the case.